# Форматированный вывод чисел с плавающей точкой

Tags: c++

Проблема заключается в следующем: мне необходимо осуществить вывод некоторых переменных типа `double` без экспоненты (пример: 3.80397e+006). Я пробовал выставлять `std::fixed`, но тогда возникает другая проблема, а именно из-за фиксированного количества знаков после запятой, если в выводимом числе знаков после запятой меньше, чем установлено, то к нему дописываются нули. Можно ли каким нибудь образом выполнить оба требуемых для меня условий? (без фиксированного числа знаков после запятой и без экспоненты)

Comment: связанный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/q/277772/4279

Comment: Можно самому написать какое угодно форматирование.